# Layout HTML e CSS. Como faço para torná-lo responsivo?

Tags: html, css

Queria ver uma forma de tornar o código abaixo como se fossem duas colunas, que se fosse aberto em um celular a 1° coluna e a 2° ficassem uma embaixo da outra.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

body
{
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 13px;
   line-height: 1.1875;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

/* As imagens e os textos 1, 2, 3 , 4 gostaria que ficasse de um lado caso a pagina fosse dimunuida ou vista de um celular */

/* E o restante para baixo caso dê para ser responsivo */
#wb_Text1 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text1 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
#Picture1
{
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 50px;
   height: 100%;
}
#Picture2
{
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
#MediaPlayer1
{
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
#wb_Text2 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text2 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text3 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text3 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text4 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text4 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text5 
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0px solid #000000;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   text-align: left;
}
#wb_Text5 div
{
   text-align: left;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #16595c;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: autopx;
  height: autopx;  
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #16595c;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: autopx;
  height: autopx;  
}

a
{
   color: #0000FF;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited
{
   color: #800080;
}
a:active
{
   color: #FF0000;
}
a:hover
{
   color: #0000FF;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
h1, .h1
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 32px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
h2, .h2
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 27px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
h3, .h3
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
h4, .h4
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
h5, .h5
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 19px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
h6, .h6
{
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #000000;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   display: inline;
}
.CustomStyle
{
   font-family: "Courier New";
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #2E74B5;
   background-color: transparent;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:8px;width:341px;height:32px;z-index:0;">
<h2>11:14 Destino Fatal</h2></div>
<picture id="wb_Picture1" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:40px;width:106px;height:29px;z-index:1">
<img src="https://d26oc3sg82pgk3.cloudfront.net/files/media/callsheet/agentlogos/logo_Media8.jpg" id="Picture1" alt="" srcset="">
</picture>
<picture id="wb_Picture2" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:77px;width:324px;height:460px;z-index:2">
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71FexVgesIL._SY445_.jpg" id="Picture2" alt="" srcset="">
</picture>
<div id="wb_MediaPlayer1" style="position:absolute;left:341px;top:77px;width:693px;height:460px;z-index:3;">
<video src="" id="MediaPlayer1" autoplay controls>
</video>
</div>
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:217px;top:59px;width:95px;height:15px;z-index:4;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;"><strong>Director:</strong></span></div>
<div id="wb_Text3" style="position:absolute;left:270px;top:59px;width:103px;height:14px;z-index:5;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;">Greg Marcks</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text4" style="position:absolute;left:121px;top:46px;width:70px;height:16px;z-index:6;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">2003</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text5" style="position:absolute;left:625px;top:33px;width:154px;height:29px;z-index:7;">
<h3>TRAILERS</h3></div>
<div id="Html1" style="position:absolute;left:8px;top:545px;width:324px;height:51px;z-index:8">
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div id="rcorners1">
<div class="tooltip"><b>Starring:</b>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Henry Thomas,
  <span class="tooltiptext"> <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWNjZjc1NTYtZmY2Mi00MjZhLWE4ZjYtYTMyNWFmYjRkZDdmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTAyNzUwOTA5._V1_.jpg" style="width:200px; height: 300px"></span>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Colin Hanks,
  <span class="tooltiptext"> <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWNjZjc1NTYtZmY2Mi00MjZhLWE4ZjYtYTMyNWFmYjRkZDdmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTAyNzUwOTA5._V1_.jpg" style="width:200px; height: 300px"></span>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Ben Foster
  <span class="tooltiptext"> <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWNjZjc1NTYtZmY2Mi00MjZhLWE4ZjYtYTMyNWFmYjRkZDdmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTAyNzUwOTA5._V1_.jpg" style="width:200px; height: 300px"></span>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html></div>
<div id="Html2" style="position:absolute;left:341px;top:554px;width:701px;height:51px;z-index:9">
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div id="rcorners1">
<div class="tooltip"><b>Categories:</b>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Crime,
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Drama,
</div>
<div class="tooltip">Misterio,
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não consigo te dar uma boa resposta agora, mas os vc ta procurando é @media no css, se entender um pouco de inglês, da uma olhada nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, tenha muito cuidado na utilização das tags, você está abrindo um `<html>` e um `<body>` para cada conteúdo e não se deve fazer isso. Monte toda a sua estrutura dentro da tag `<body>` e depois utilize `<div>`, `<section>`, etc., como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Minha Página</title>
</head>
<body>

<main id='page-content'>
    <section id='sect-one'>
        <!-- CONTEÚDO DA SESSÃO 1 -->
    </section>

    <section id='sect-two'>
        <!-- CONTEÚDO DA SESSÃO 2 -->
    </section>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Feito isso, para deixar as duas `<section>` lado a lado é simples, utilizando `display: flex`:

```
#page-content {
   width:100%;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-between;
}

#sect-one, #sect-two {
   width:50%;
}
```

No código acima, defini o tamanho de 50% para cada uma das `<section>`, pois assim elas ficarão lado a lado em monitores desktop.

Agora para ficar uma abaixo da outra no **mobile** basta utilizar o `@media` do CSS. Como não foi estipulado nenhum tamanho de tela, vou trabalhar com o tamanho máximo de *768px*:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
   #page-content {
      flex-direction: column;
   }

   #sect-one, #sect-two {
      width:100%;
   }
}
```

Defini que em telas menores que *768px* o layout será orientado em **coluna** ao invés de linhas como vem no `flex` por padrão, e também alterei a largura dos dois blocos para preencherem 100% da tela, o código final ficaria assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Minha Página</title>
</head>

<style>
    #page-content {
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
    }

    #sect-one, #sect-two {
        width:50%;

        /* APENAS PARA VISUALIZAR, PODE APAGAR! */
        height: 500px;
        background-color:red;


    }

    @media(max-width:768px) {
        #page-content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #sect-one, #sect-two {
            width:100%;
        }
    }
</style>

<body>

<main id='page-content'>
    <section id='sect-one'>
        <!-- CONTEÚDO DA SESSÃO 1 -->
    </section>

    <section id='sect-two'>
        <!-- CONTEÚDO DA SESSÃO 2 -->
    </section>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Colocando o conteúdo da sua página separado em cada bloco, vai resolver o seu problema. Mas de qualquer forma vale lembrar para ficar atento nas tags que você utiliza. Sugiro que pesquise um pouco sobre **HTML semântico**.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Mateus, eu estou tentando colocar o conteúdo a partir de seu código mas não consigo deixar o layout igual ou semelhante ao que eu enviei, mas a sua sugestão é o que eu preciso. Vamos pode conversar no chat?